# How do I change the default "www.example.com" domain for testing in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a rails application which acts differently depending on what domain it's accessed at (for example www.myapp.com will invoke differently to user.myapp.com). In production use this all works fine but my test code always sees a hostname of "www.example.com".

Is there a clean way of having a test specify the hostname it's pretending to access?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
@request.host = 'user.myapp.com'
```

Comment: In a controller spec, I get an error when trying to use `host!`. Setting `@request.host` like the answer suggests worked though.

Comment: And how do I use it with RSpec? I mean, where do I configure it? many thanks!

Comment: @FRAGA : Configuration in RSpec: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7050306/2066546. `Capybara.app_host = "http://example.com"` has worked for me.

Answer (score 126):

- **Integration/Request Specs** (inheriting from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`):

  ```
   host! 'my.awesome.host'
  ```

See the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing), section 5.1 *Helpers Available for Integration Tests*.

alternatively, configure it globally for request specs at spec_helper.rb level:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :request) do
    host! 'my.awesome.host'
  end
end
```

- **Controller Specs** (inheriting from `ActionController::TestCase`)

  ```
   @request.host = 'my.awesome.host'
  ```

See the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers), section 4.4 *Instance Variables Available*.

- **Feature Specs**  (through Capybara)

  ```
   Capybara.default_host = 'http://my.awesome.host'
   # Or to configure domain for route helpers:
   default_url_options[:host] = 'my.awesome.host'
  ```

From [@AminAriana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28683776/143243)

- **View Specs** (inheriting from `ActionView::TestCase`)

  ```
   @request.host = 'my.awesome.host'
  ```

...or through RSpec:

```
    controller.request.host = 'my.awesome.host'
```

See the `rspec-rails` [view spec docs](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.6/rspec-rails/#View_specs).

Comment: Thanks to rails 5 and switching from `ActionController::TestCase` to `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` this top `Integration Specs` is invaluable to those of us with legacy multi-tennant apps. This was the first answer that showed how to get `@request.host` easily converted into an older suite (by using `host!`). Reading the docs this didn't jump out at me but here we are, and thanks!

Comment: Where does that `default_url_options[:host] = "my.awesome.host"` go?

Comment: I don't recall well, it's been a while. Does it not work if you place it in the main body of a feature spec?

Comment: For anyone using type: :request tests, I discovered that the path and url helpers were causing the problems with "example.com". It looks like a string should be used instead of the helpers.

Answer (score 33):

### Feature specs

In Feature specs, host! has been deprecated. Add these to your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
# Configure Capybara expected host
Capybara.app_host = "http://test.domain"

# Configure actual routes host during test
before(:each) do
  default_url_options[:host] = <myhost>
end
```

### Request specs

In Request specs, keep using host! :

```
host! "test.domain"
```

Alternatively refactor it in `before(:each)` blocks, or configure it globally for request specs at `spec_helper.rb` level:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :request) do
    host! "test.domain"
  end
end
```

Comment: Note: It seems like `Capybara.app_host` needs to include the protocol. E.g. `"http://test.domain"` rather than just `"test.domain"`.

Comment: how to include the port?

Comment: The amount of time wasted on this is ridiculous. Thanks. This is about the only thing that worked. Why in the world this wouldn't "just work" by defining the default url options in Rails `config/environments/test.rb` is beyond me.

Comment: @MaximKrizhanovsky Disregard `host!` and use something like `setup do
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = {
      port: "3000",
      host: "localhost"
    }
  end`

Answer (score 9):

For Rspec Request specs, use `before(:each) { host! 'example.com' }`

See more at: 
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-6/docs/request-specs/request-spec
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1662#issuecomment-241201056

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can modify the `HTTP_HOST` or `SERVER_NAME` environment vars to change the request that goes to the router:

```
ENV['SERVER_NAME'] = "user.myapp.com"
```

See `raw_host_with_port` in [actionpack/lib/action_controller/request.rb](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8607740a29d0f9ceb2ca21c9ef714f74b64d4a88/actionpack/lib/action_controller/request.rb).

Answer (score 5):

Another thing to remember is to make sure to use the **correct session instance** so that you can properly encapsulate the url helpers.

Integration tests provide you with a default session. You can call [all session methods](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Integration/Session) directly from your tests

```
test "should integrate well" do
  https!
  get users_path
  assert_response :success
end
```

All these helpers are using the default session instance, which if not changed, goes to "www.example.com". As has been mentioned the host can be changed by doing host!("my.new.host")

If you create multiple sessions using the open_session method, you must ALWAYS use that instance to call the helper methods. This will properly encapsulate the request. Otherwise rails will call the default session instance which may use a different host:

```
test "should integrate well" do
  sess = open_session
  sess.host! "my.awesome.host"
  sess.get users_url             #=> WRONG! will use default session object to build url.
  sess.get sess.users_url        #=> Correctly invoking url writer from my custom session with new host.
  sess.assert_response :success
end
```

If you intended to use the default session object, then you'll have to alter that host as well:

```
test "should integrate well" do
  sess = open_session
  sess.host! "my.awesome.host"
  host! sess.host              #=> Set default session host to my custom session host.
  sess.get users_url
end
```

Comment: I've been stuck on this problem all day and adding before(:each) { https! } is the only thing that worked. Wish I could upvote this more.

Answer (score 3):

`@request.host = 'user.myapp.com'` is not right.
should use `host!('user.myapp.com')`

Comment: This syntax did not work for me. Neither did the accepted answer. The only thing that worked as host!('newhostname.com').

Comment: Of course you need to put the string of the host name in single or double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many variations of `@request.host`, `host!`, and `post path, args, {'SERVER_NAME' => my_secret_domain}` without success, both as controller tests and feature tests.  Very aggravating, as so many others reported success with those approaches.

The solution for me was:

```
request.headers["SERVER_NAME"] = my_secret_domain
post path, args
```

I'm running ruby 2.1.5p273, rspec 3.1.7 and Rails 4.2.0

Answer (score 1):

None of the ways suggested in other answers at the point worked for me. This worked:

```
Capybara.configure { |config| config.default_host = "my.domain.com" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer:

```
request.host = "user.myapp.com"
```

I know it resembles the correct answer, but please bear with me. I don't like assignment operation in test just to set things up, I'd prefer an explicit stub. Interestingly, stubbing like this **won't** work:

```
allow(request).to receive(:host).and_return("user.myapp.com")
```

I personally prefer stubbing over assignment, that way I get 2 benefit, one is that it will be validated by **rspec's verify double**, second is that it is explicitly saying that is a stub, not part of the test excercise.

Comment: The difference at the start of this answer is you use a local variable or method call instead of an instance variable. Then you go on to talk about stubbing instead of assignment. I would suggest against that style because although it seems you're getting extra checks, you're actually adding an unnecessary dependency on the stubbing framework. It should be clear here what's setup and what's not. The test should fail if setting the domain does not work. Or just add an assert that the domain is what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

in `test_helper.rb`

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  before { host! Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:host] }
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?