# Capybara with subdomains - default_host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, capybara

I have an app that uses subdomains to switch databases (multi-tenancy).  I'm trying to use Capybara for integration testing, and it really relies a lot on subdomains.

My understanding was that setting `Capybara.default_host=` to something would make all my requests come from this host.  This doesn't seem to be the case.  In [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/browse_thread/thread/b7417b4d7c1b74bf), the author recommends just visiting the explicit url with a host, but this becomes a bit annoying if I'm navigating all over the place.  I'd like to just set the host, then be able to use my rails paths as expected.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but here's what I've tried:

```
# spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, :type => :request) do
    Capybara.default_host = 'http://app.mydomain.com'
  end
end

# in some_integration_spec.rb
before do
  puts "Capybara.default_host: #{Capybara.default_host}"
  puts "some_app_url: #{some_app_url}"
end
```

This yields the output:

```
Capybara.default_host: http://app.mydomain.com
some_app_url: http://www.example.com/some_path
```

What am I doing wrong?  `default_host` appears to do nothing.  As I say, I don't want to have to say `visit(Capybara.default_host + some_app_path)` as that's a bit annoying each time.  Why else does this default_host option exist?

Comment: Maybe could be helpful to someone [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18476731/895789)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I'm not sure of the intended use of `default_host`, but `app_host` does what you need. I've found I first need to call the rails session method `host!` in order to set the host string that will be passed to controllers in the request object.

Then you need to set `Capybara.app_host` to tell Capybara to call your app via the web server instead of just making the calls in process. If you don't do that then Capybara wigs out when it encounters redirects and drops the host information in the second request.

I'm not sure why this doesn't take care of the Rails `request` end of things automatically, but I've found that unless I set the host in both places explicitly, then I get inconsistent results.

```
def set_host (host)
  host! host
  Capybara.app_host = "http://" + host
end

before(:each) do
  set_host "lvh.me:3000"
end
```

Then you can just use relative paths to access pages.

**Update:**

**Capybara 2.x** and **rspec-rails 2.12.0** introduced "Feature" specs for running Capybara acceptance tests. The new `FeatureExampleGroup` module in `rspec-rails` is different from `RequestExampleGroup` and no longer has access to the rack-test `host!` method. Now you want to use `default_url_options` instead:

```
def set_host (host)
  # host! host
  default_url_options[:host] = host
  Capybara.app_host = "http://" + host
end
```

Comment: interesting... i'll take a look at this when i get a chance. thx!

Comment: looks like app_host is the winner, i wish the docs were more clear as to the difference,  thanks!

Comment: This works perfectly. Also, if you're using a public domain like `lvh.me` you can set the port automatically using `Capybara.server_port = 31234`, and then `set_host "lvh.me:31234"`

Comment: default host is useful for something like this `after(:each) do
    Capybara.app_host = Capybara.default_host
  end`

Comment: I works but when I have: visit new_sessions_path/url I got error page that the domain is example and it should be used for testing. :/

Answer (score 33):

When you need to change the URL to include the subdomain, you can specify the `app_host` in your step definitions. Use a domain like `lvh.me` since it points to `127.0.0.1`:

```
Capybara.app_host = "http://#{subdomain}.lvh.me"
```

Capybara assumes that when you're specifying an `app_host` that you're testing a remote server running on port 80, but in our case, we're testing a local app which is running on a random port specified by Capybara. To fix this, in your `env.rb` file, add this line:

```
Capybara.always_include_port = true
```

Now when you visit a page of your app...

```
visit '/page'
```

...the url will specify the subdomain as well as the port that the app is running on.

FYI: This worked for me using Capybara 2.0.2.

Comment: This method works for me also, and none of the other methods work. I'm on Capybara 2.4.3. For my application, I also want to know the port number that was selected by Capybara, from inside my testing environment. I'm using Poltergeist/PhantomJS, and I can get that info from this call: ```Capybara.current_session.server.port```

Answer (score 6):

This guy has the right answer here:

http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Testing_Subdomains_in_Capybara-g4M

You want to do

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.reset!
Capybara.default_host = 'http://app.mydomain.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

as of:

- capybara (2.4.1)
- capybara-webkit (1.3.0)

  ```
  Capybara.server_host = "example.com"
  Capybara.server_port = 3050
  Capybara.run_server = true
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit #requires capybara-webkit
  ```

Comment: This seems to be a mistake, as the most recent version of capybara is 2.13.0.

Comment: @Sirasis yes 2.13 will be later than 2.4

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the same situation as you but this might help some people:

For my current project, I'm using [pow](http://pow.cx) with many subdomains. The test suite also has to run on a different port.

The solution depends on which version of capybara you're running.

For the current latest release I put this in custom_env.rb:

```
Capybara.server_host = 'myapp.dev'
Capybara.server_port = 9887
Capybara.run_server = true

# I don't remember what this was for. Another team member wrote this part...
module ActionDispatch
  module Integration #:nodoc:
    class Session
      def host
        [Capybara.server_host, Capybara.server_port].join(':')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

With capybara 1.1.2, I had had to make the above change but `server_host` becomes `app_host` AND modify lib/capybara/server.rb in the gem like this:

```
def url(path)
  ..
  if path =~ /^http/
    path
  else
    # Was this (Capybara.app_host || "http://#{host}:#{port}") + path.to_s
    (Capybara.app_host || "http://#{host}") + ":#{port}" + path.to_s
  end
end
```