# @javascript tag not working for cucumber test cases using capybara driver

Tags: cucumber, capybara-webkit

I am getting this error when using @javascript tag for scenario :

Unable to load URL: http://testdomain.mentorstring.com:3000/login because of error loading http://testdomain.mentorstring.com:3000/login: Unknown error (Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError).

when i am running the same without javascript tag i get no error and the test passes.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely an error on the page. Check your browser console when loading the page. Also, see more details here: [Capybara webkit invalid response error, how to debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757118/capybara-webkit-invalid-response-error-how-to-debug)

This answer also provides a way to debug it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12194920/769971

Comment: i did the need full changes that i got from those links , but the problem is still persisiting

Answer (score 0):

Try using following capybara configurations in your env.rb file

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = true
  config.server_port = 3000
  config.javascript_driver = :webkit
  config.default_wait_time = 30
  config.always_include_port = true
  config.default_host = 'your_app_url'
  config.app_host = 'http://your_app_url'
end
```