# no route error in test works in dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

so I have a route api.gemstore.dev/gems (using pow)
in the browser I get an empty array [] which is perfect, there isn't anything in the db yet, so I should get an empty array

in my rspec test I have

```
  setup do
    host! 'api.gemstore.dev'
  end

  test 'As a user, I want to get gems' do
    get '/gems', {}, { 'Accept' => Mime::JSON }
    assert_equal 200, response.status
    assert_equal Mime::JSON, response.content_type
  end
```

routes

```
  namespace :api, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do
    resources :gems
  end
```

rake routes

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
   api_gems GET    /gems(.:format)          api/gems#index   {:subdomain=>"api"}
               POST   /gems(.:format)          api/gems#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
   new_api_gem GET    /gems/new(.:format)      api/gems#new {:subdomain=>"api"}
  edit_api_gem GET    /gems/:id/edit(.:format) api/gems#edit {:subdomain=>"api"}
       api_gem GET    /gems/:id(.:format)      api/gems#show {:subdomain=>"api"}
               PATCH  /gems/:id(.:format)      api/gems#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
               PUT    /gems/:id(.:format)      api/gems#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
               DELETE /gems/:id(.:format)      api/gems#destroy {:subdomain=>"api"}
              root GET    /                           static#index
```

but this comes back with a no route matches error

let me know if you need more info, happy to provide, just not sure what to provide

Comment: That looks like minitest not rspec. As Mario's answer says, check whether you're writing a controller test or an integration test.

Answer (score 1):

Probably host isn't being set up correctly.

- `host! "my.awesome.host"` for integration specs (inheriting from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`). See the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing), section **5.1 Helpers Available for Integration Tests**.
- `@request.host = 'my.awesome.host'` for controller specs (inheriting from `ActionController::TestCase`). See the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers), section **4.4 Instance Variables Available**.
- If using Capybara, [check this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536503/capybara-with-subdomains-default-host/7050306#7050306)

Comment: host! "my.awesome.host"  this is exactly what I have!
thank you for looking.  but I'm afraid your just as stumped as me.  I think my mac hates me.  I suppose it's what I get for hating macs for so long

Comment: Try the @request.host bit