# Why does `log/test.log` show `http://www.example.com/` in the `Redirected to` message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, integration-testing

I'm running integration tests to make sure my `before_filter` is redirecting to `root_path` if the user is not logged in. Everything seems to be working fine, but I'm seeing `http://www.example.com/` in the `Redirected to` message in `log/test.log`, and I'm just wondering if this is normal, or if there's a configuration that I missed somewhere. Thanks!

**log/test.log**

```
Started PUT "/users/980190963" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-29 13:31:39 -0700
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "id"=>"980190963"}
Redirected to http://www.example.com/
Filter chain halted as :reject_if_logged_out rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
...
before_filter :reject_if_logged_out, only: [:update]
...
private
def reject_if_logged_out
  redirect_to root_path unless @current_user
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Strangely enough, only some of my apps seems to do this. But this has been answered here before, it's the default and here's how to change it: [How do I change the default "www.example.com" domain for testing in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598933/how-do-i-change-the-default-www-example-com-domain-for-testing-in-rails)

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the default in in capybara, the library that cucumber and many other testing frameworks for rails use. See [`lib/capybara.rb`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara.rb#L360):

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.default_host = "http://www.example.com"
  # ...
end
```

So if you do not specify anything else in your configuration the default value for `@request.host` is `www.example.com`.