# test.host in Rspec testing Rails redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Here's a line from my `test.rb` environnment file in a Rails 3.1.12 app:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = config.action_controller.default_url_options = { :host => "127.0.0.1", :port => 3000 }
```

Now here's the test I make:

```
subject { get :success }
subject.should redirect_to(:home)
```

This produces an error:

```
Failure/Error: subject.should redirect_to(:home)
       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://127.0.0.1:3000/> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/>
```

What did I do wrong? Or else, where the testing host be configured?

Here's the spec_helper.rb file for complete reference.

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.app_host    = 'http://127.0.0.1'
  config.server_port = 3000
end
```

Comment: I'm still running into this on Rails 5.2 and rspec-rails 3.9. Ridiculous. Using `_path` instead of `_url` for now to get around it.

Comment: Comprehensive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29037481/109175

Answer (score 7):

To set the app host and server port with Capybara add the following lines to your `spec/spec_helper.rb` file

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.app_host   = 'http://127.0.0.1'
  config.server_port = 3000
end
```

-- Edit #1

A nice overview of testing domains is available at http://blog.joncairns.com/2012/12/testing-domains-with-rails-and-test-unit/

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I've updated the question with the spec helper content.

Comment: Do you still receive the same error message when you add the Capybara config options?

Comment: Yes. Same error. To get around this, I've used `home_path` instead for now. But this doesn't check the domain, which is a problem on the long term.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
# spec/controllers/whatever_controller_spec.rb
before :each do
  @request.host = '127.0.0.1:3000'
end
```

Based on the link @dan-reedy supplied.  It is sublimely annoying to have to configure the exact same parameters in config/environments, spec/spec_helper.rb and again here... all in marginally different ways (with 'http://' or without, with port number or port specified separately).  Even `Capybara.configure` syntax can't seem to stay consistent to itself between versions...

But give it a try and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the workaround that seems to have fixed the issue for me:

In spec/rails_helper.rb add this

```
module ActionDispatch
  class TestRequest
    # Override host, by default it is test.host
    def host
      'localhost:3000'
    end
  end
end
```