# rspec controller redirect test failing due to different domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Using Rails 4.0, rspec 3.4 (and Capybara 2.7), I have a very simple controller and controller spec. Authentication is via devise 3.5:

Model:

```
class DraftsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_draft, only: [:show, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @drafts = Draft.all
    respond_with(@drafts)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@draft)
  end

  def new
    @draft = Draft.new
    respond_with(@draft)
  end

  def create
    @draft = Draft.new(draft_params)
    @draft.save
    respond_with(@draft)
  end

  def destroy
    @draft.destroy
    respond_with(@draft)
  end

  private
    def set_draft
      @draft = Draft.find(params[:id])
    end

    def draft_params
      params.require(:draft).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Spec (abridged)

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe DraftsController, type: :controller do
  let(:valid_attributes) {
    { name: 'Test One' }
  }

  context "when signed in" do
    login_user

    describe "DELETE #destroy" do
      it "redirects to the drafts list" do
        draft = Draft.create! valid_attributes
        delete :destroy, {:id => draft.to_param}
        expect(response).to redirect_to(drafts_url)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

My test.rb environment file defines:

```
config.after_initialize do
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
end
```

When I run the test, it fails with:

```
  1) DraftsController when signed in DELETE #destroy redirects to the drafts list
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(drafts_url)

       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://localhost:3000/drafts> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/drafts>.
       Expected "http://localhost:3000/drafts" to be === "http://test.host/drafts".
```

It seems that the test is generating the url based on Rails' config, but some part of the test framework (I don't know where) is supplying the host as `test.host`. How can I make them agree?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414847/test-host-in-rspec-testing-rails-redirect)?

Comment: @Wikiti - yes. I have tried those lines in my `rails_helper.rb`; they make no difference.

Comment: just out of curiousity, is there any reason you're not using the `drafts_path`?

Comment: @oreoluwa - Nothing on my part. The test is exactly as `rails g scaffold` created it.