# RSpec controller testing http://test.host/login error on index spec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am creating controller tests for my application. I am just trying to test the index action for my `maps_controller`.

I created this test for the index to see if it renders.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MapsController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    it 'shows a list of all maps' do
      get :index
      expect(response).to redirect_to maps_path
    end
  end
end
```

However when I run this spec test I get this error message.

> Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to maps_path
>
> Expected response to be a redirect to http://test.host/maps but was a redirect to http://test.host/login.
>          Expected "http://test.host/maps" to be === "http://test.host/login".

I can understand this because it does require a user to get to this path. However, I am unsure why this is trying to go to http://test.host/maps instead of `localhost:3000/maps`. I was unable to find anything in RSpec docs about setting the test url. How can I set this to go to `localhost:3000` instead of `test.host`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [test.host in Rspec testing Rails redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414847/test-host-in-rspec-testing-rails-redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it globally in your `spec_helper.rb` file:

Since your spec is set to `type: :controller`, you would do it this way:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # other config options

  config.before(:each) do
    @request.host = "localhost:3000"
  end
end
```

However, as of RSpec 3.5 the preferred method of testing controllers is with a `:request` spec. So if possible, change your spec to `type: :request` and then you would do it this way:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # other config options

  config.before(:each) do
    host! "localhost:3000"
  end
end
```

Comment: This gives me this error `Failure/Error: host! "localhost:3000"

      NoMethodError:
        undefined method host!' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserPolicy::IsATeacher:0x007fc9ede223b8>` and causes all tests to fail.

Comment: Did you put it in `spec_helper.rb` or `rails_helper.rb`? Could you toss your `spec_helper.rb` file into a pastebin and share it here so I can take a look?

Comment: @TrentonTyler Ahh, okay I figured it out. It's not working because your spec `type:` is set to `:controller` rather than `:request`. Best way to fix would be to change your spec `type`. But if that’s not doable, instead of `host!` do `@request.host = "localhost:3000”` and it should work. Updated the answer to reflect both scenarios.

Comment: @TrentonTyler correct. Though it's slightly more nuanced. Per Rails core: Request specs allow you to focus on a single controller action, but unlike controller tests involve the router, the middleware stack, and both rack requests and responses. It's now recommended to use `spec/requests/mycontroller_request_spec.rb`. There will be some differences but generally request specs are much more intuitive and easier to use. **Edit**: ah, you deleted your comment. well there's the info in any case.

Answer (score 0):

its work for me

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(type: :request) do
    host! "localhost:3000"
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a new answer, or a vote for the existing answer?

Comment: Is this  a new answer

Answer (score 0):

set default hosts in environment configuration:

`config/environments/test.rb`

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://localhost' }
  config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'http://localhost' }
```

also, you probably want set default host for request, then you can override default value in `rails_helper.rb` like:

```
module ActionDispatch
  class TestRequest
    def host
      'localhost'
    end
  end
end
```

That should be enought.