# rails root_url redirects me to www.example.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm getting something really weird when I execute my tests with `rails test`.

I'm trying to understand and create my first controller tests and I get something unexpected.

I get this error in the console:

```
F

Failure:
FeedbacksControllerTest#test_should_create_resource [/Users/Daniel/GitHub/haeapua-rails/test/controllers/feedbacks_controller_test.rb:15]:
Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://www.example.com/>
Response body: <html><body>You are being <a href="http://www.example.com/">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

here is my test

```
test "should create resource" do

  assert_difference 'Feedback.count', 1 do 
    post feedbacks_url, params: { feedback: { email: "me@myemail.com", summary: "my feedback", rating: 5 } }
  end

  assert_response :success
  assert_redirected_to root_url
end
```

here is my controller

```
class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController

  # GET /feedbacks/new
  def new
    @feedback = Feedback.new
    # @feedback.user = current_user if user_signed_in?
  end

  # POST /feedbacks
  def create
    @feedback = Feedback.new(feedback_params)
    # @feedback.user = current_user if user_signed_in?

    if @feedback.save
      # flash[:info] = "We got it, thanks. Someone will contact you ASAP once we read it"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def feedback_params
      params.require(:feedback).permit(:email, :summary, :rating)
    end
end
```

When I put a "puts root_url" in my feedback controller just before the redirect_to I get the value `"http://www.example.com/"`. I search for `root_url` in my whole code and the only part I have it is in the Controller and in my routes `root to: 'static_pages#concept'`

I'm using devise, do you think it could be because of that? I'm a bit lost and don't know where to start looking!

Comment: do you use capybara ?

Comment: Yes I do have the gem installed. Hum, will look into it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some default config is setting this value. https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara.rb#L452

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.default_host = "http://www.example.com"
  # ...
end
```

You have to override this setting in your project config.

---

If it's not capybara it could be rails issue ? From the input of this thread https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1275 I would try something like this

```
# config/environment/test.rb
config.action_controller.default_url_options = {
  host: '0.0.0.0:3000' # or whatever your host is
}
```

---

In the thread I found:

```
# putting this into initializer of test framework
[ApplicationController, ActionController::Base].each do |klass|
  klass.class_eval do
    def default_url_options(options = {})
      { :host => "example.com" }.merge(options) # or localhost:8888 or 0.0.0.0:3000 or whatever your server is
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I commented the Gem in m Gemfile but it still does it. I still can't figure out where this value is defined. It has to be somewhere...

Comment: just be sure, did you `$ bundle install` after commenting it out ?

Answer (score -1):

It's a weird quirk but rails has two types of url_helpers for routes. something_url and something_path. The first is an absolute path, http://www.awesome.com/something) the second is the relative path (/someurl).

Unless you have a domain name set explicitly on your test environment, use the _path helpers in your tests. If you want to use the _url helpers then you need to configure a base url in your application's test environment (config/environments/test.rb)

Comment: I know about the _path and _url. But your answer doesn't explain why I have example.com set by default.

Comment: well you may know about them but you're using _url in your tests with assert redirected_to root_url instead of root_path, and you don't have a domain set in your environment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48865478/793330

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is wrong on doing that?