# How to retreive host url in development and production in Rails/Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, request, httparty

I'm creating tests for my `senders_controller` and am trying to retrieve my base url to be able to call an HTTParty request. I basically need the same method to be able to retrieve me one of these two links depending on the environment:

- in development: `http://localhost:3100/senders`
- in production: `https://example.com/senders`

My tests work in my `spec/senders_controller.rb` like this:

```
HTTParty.post("http://localhost:3100/senders", query: {email: user.email})
```

But I want that link to also work in production, which is why I'm looking for a dynamic way to get the base url in both development and production.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to use development (http://localhost:3100) and production(https://example.com) as a base URL for the spec or for the code in the controller? You can use `request.base_url` for the latter. For the former, perhaps this may help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29037481/7485031

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option that I have used in the past is to use the [config](https://github.com/railsconfig/config) gem.

You can create variables for different environments and then just call that variable.

For example, you can have a `config/settings/development.yml` that defines the url one way:

`base_url: "http://localhost:3100/senders"`

And a `config/settings/production.yml` file that defines it another:

`base_url: "https://example.com/senders"`

Then call it with `Settings.base_url`

It automatically resolves the environment and populates the correct settings for that environment.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thank you, worked like a charm 

Answer (score 2):

Try this, nice and simple:

```
url = Rails.env.development? ? "localhost:3100/senders" : "example.com/senders"

HTTParty.post(url, query: {email: user.email})
```

Comment: I had to pass in `Rails.env.test` rather than `Rails.env.development` since I was using the links for testing. It should have worked except for other configuration I had.. Great idea, though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Would you mind accepting this answer if it was helpful and got you to your end goal? Thanks!